# Codenameone: How to access calendar on Android

Tags: codenameone

In my app I use the CN1 Calendar lib to access the device calendar. I added the Android-build-hints so that my app is allowed to access the calendar (I can proof this in the App-Settings). But the method deviceCalender.getCalendars() returns null - which is documented with "no permissions". What can I do to access the calendar on an Android device? (btw: It works fine on iOS).

Test-Device: HUAWEI P-Smart with Android 8.0.0.138

This is the code I used:

```
if (deviceCalender.hasPermissions())
{
    Collection<String> cals = deviceCalender.getCalendars();

    if( cals != null )
    {
        System.out.println("Length of Calendar-List: " + cals.size());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No permission on getCalendars()");
    }
}
else
    System.out.println("No permission on hasPermissions()");
```

In Android-Studio I only get this console-output:

```
2019-07-25 11:30:35.185 25342-25375/de.zeitkuenstlervoll.gtd.gui I/System.out: No permission on getCalendars()
```

I attached a screenshot from the device where you can see, that the app has the permission to access calendar.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The build hint isn't enough, you must use:

```
DeviceCalendar dc = DeviceCalendar.getInstance();
if(!dc.hasPermissions()) {
    // show message 
    return;
}
```

Which prompts for permission. Android 6 and newer lets you see which permissions are granted to the app.

Comment: This is exactly what the code in my app does: dc.hasPermissions() returns true - but deviceCalender.getCalendars() returns null.

Comment: i suggest editing the question with more details then. Try adding the code, whether the permission is indeed granted in the device UI. Which devices you tried this on (and their OS versions). Applicable console output on the device (if any).

Comment: I added all the information I can gather in the question above. Hope you can give me a hint how to get a solution for this problem. Is it possible, that the calendar I can see as the local calendar in the android calendar app is not the android device-calendar? So the getCalendars() cannot find any calendar when asking android?

Comment: I see this, it's possible this is something google broke with newer versions of their API but I can't find references for that at this time. You can file an issue on that and we'll have a look.

Comment: I filed an issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2871

Comment: I can't get it to work on Android either. I added my comment to the issue filed above.